# Installing mysqlnd for php 5.6 on CentOs 7

Tags: mysql, php

I get php warning:

> mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50547 Library:50624

Also I read that I need to install mysqlnd to my server. I tried do it using:

> yum install php-mysqlnd

but get error:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /etc/php.ini from install of php-common-5.5.34-1.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php56w-common-5.6.20-1.w7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/....
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first uninstall the conflicting package before you're able to install the php-mysqlnd:

```
yum remove php56w-common

yum install php-mysqlnd
```